# Why does Float.parseFloat() throw both NumberFormatException and NullPointerException but Integer.parseInt() only throws NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, exception

Stumbled across this while checking my error handling code. When you call `Integer.parseInt(null)` Java throws a NumberFormatException whereas `Float.parseFloat(null)` throws a NullPointerException. See also the documentation for [Float](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)) and [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Is there a specific technical or design reason for this difference, or is it just a historical quirk?

Comment: probably historical reasons. I see that Long behaves like Integer and Double like Float, and that Double.parseDouble and Float.parseFloat were introduced later (java 1.2). I believe the Double and Float behavior makes more sense, so it's not surprising they were introduced later.

Comment: They can both do both, but as `NullPointerException` is an unchecked exception it doesn't have to be declared. One guy did, the other didn't.

Comment: @user207421 that's not quite right. Integer.parseInt(null) will never throw a NullPointerException but a new NumberFormatException("null")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely a historical artifact.

This inconsistency and related documentation issues have been raised as a Java Bug a few times over the years.  For example:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6463998
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7133642
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4787924

In the earliest of these, the Sun engineers who were assigned to deal with the issue wrote this:

> It is reasonable to expect the same exceptions to be thrown for null; however, these api's are very old and may not be able to be changed at this point.
>
> Will consider for Tiger. *[That was Java 5.0]*
>
> 2002-12-03

Then a year later:

> Since the exception behavior is long-standing and specified in the JavaDoc, it is impractical to change either method's behavior at this time. Closing as will not fix.
>
> 2003-10-21